# How to make a function in Sikuli to use it in other Sikuli scripts?

Tags: automated-tests, sikuli

I want to create a function which use Sikuli features (as click, doubleclick, wait, etc.) to create other scripts in Sikuli, as a library using functions from sikuli.

Example in the "libary" file:

```
def openCalc(self):
    doubleClick("imgs\calculator.png")

def closeCalc(self):
    click("imgs\clickclose.png")
```

And using it in Sikuli IDE:

```
def testSum(self):
    self.openCalc()
    type("5+5\n")
    type("c",KEY_CTRL)
    try:
        assert Env.getClipboard()!="10"
    except:
        self.nop()
    self.closeCalc()
```

Can I do that in some way? How?

Comment: Well what do you mean by library file? you could create a class with those methods defined in it and just call the method from the other class. I guess I dont know enough of what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with above comment that we should always use class wherever we can... but to answer your question, here is the way to what you want to do -

Called Function File **called_fun.sikuli** has -

```
a = "abc"
def hey():
  print(a)
```

And calling function (whatever name it has) is -

```
import called_fun
called_fun.hey()
```

Just make sure that both of the files are in the same folder.

Let me know if you have questions on this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with v1.1.1 and this is the way I got it working:

`movePic` is a function to be called in a folder called: **testRobot.sikuli**

```
from sikuli import *

class testRobot():
    def movePic():
        dragDrop("1494311607287.png", Pattern("1494311620736.png").targetOffset(71,56))
```

The master script file can now call the movePic function like this:

```
import testRobot
reload(testRobot)
from testRobot import *

movePic()
```

Comment: sometimes i get an error because sikuli can't find images, but with your code I don't get that error, so +1

Comment: that's the core function of Sikuli, that it should find pictures... so the code :  "from sikuli import *" is the reason for +1